# xjc error - is already defined with multiple schema files

Tags: java, xjc

We have quite a few xsd schema files created by some other source that we don't have control of. When we tried to generate java classes using xjc, we got errors complaining type already defined when they're compiled together. We looked into the customization using bindings file, but could not find anything relating to our case. With the attached xsd files, we expect to see a single TESTBody.java class is generated like:

```
public class TESTBody {
    protected MsgType1 msgType1;
    protected MsgType2 msgType2;
    protected MsgType3 msgType3;
    ...
}
```

Could anyone out there provide some help or hints?

Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:complexType name="TEST_Header">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="sender" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="receiver" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="version" type="xs:integer" />
            <xs:element name="sequenceNo" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>


</xs:schema>
```

================================

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:include schemaLocation="TEST_HeaderType.xsd" />

    <xs:element name="TEST_Message">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="TEST_Header" type="TEST_Header" />
                <xs:element name="TEST_Body" type="TEST_Body" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <!--#DOCUMENTATION:Second child element; contains the message payload-->
    <xs:complexType name="TEST_Body">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="msgType1" type="msgType1" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="msgType1">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="firstName" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="lastName" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="addressLine1" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="addressLine2" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="age" type="xs:integer" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

================================

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:include schemaLocation="TEST_HeaderType.xsd" />

    <xs:element name="TEST_Message">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="TEST_Header" type="TEST_Header" />
                <xs:element name="TEST_Body" type="TEST_Body" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <!--#DOCUMENTATION:Second child element; contains the message payload-->
    <xs:complexType name="TEST_Body">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="msgType2" type="msgType2" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="msgType2">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="className" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="teacherName" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="textBook" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="classRoom" type="xs:integer" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

================================

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:include schemaLocation="TEST_HeaderType.xsd" />

    <xs:element name="TEST_Message">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="TEST_Header" type="TEST_Header" />
                <xs:element name="TEST_Body" type="TEST_Body" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <!--#DOCUMENTATION:Second child element; contains the message payload-->
    <xs:complexType name="TEST_Body">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="msgType3" type="msgType3" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="msgType3">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="eventName" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="eventDescription" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="eventLocation" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="eventTime" type="xs:date" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

======================

Comment: You have the same type defined in 3 different schemas. What do you want XJC to do with that?! Either rename the types or give them different name-spaces.

Comment: Just wonder if there is a way to group the schema files together to generate something like the java class given above.

Comment: Yes, of course. But you need to define your types only **once**. Otherwise xjc doesn't know what to do. Just like you cannot have two classes with the same name in the same package. If you move test body to another common schema and make it abstract and then extend it in each schema that would work.

Comment: That way we need to change the schema files created by others. Is there any way to avoid changing them by using something like bindings file or something alike?

Comment: You can use bindings to push the different XMLs into different packages. This won't solve the namespace clash and therefore may not fix the issue.

Comment: I removed the common parts from the schema files and create a new one with those only and made the TEST_Body containing a choice of the individuals and got the results I wanted. Hope it works. Thanks for your help...